How to create 3 tables using EF OData concept, without foThe title key reference constraint in C table
For example A, B, C are 3 tables I want to create in A table 1 column collection of id's in B table primary key.

B table has details of that id's.
C table 2 primary keys only that is A & B tables.

When data comes from jobs that time C table received data before the B table so , some time B table have details of that may or may not but C table have id's. so without foreign key reference of b table id in C table data how to create with EF of OData concept.
Sample table creation of EF, OData
